# Missing cs classes like IdentityModel.cs and StartUp.Auth.cs in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

So i've downloaded VS17 community edition and i'm missing cs classes like IdentityModel and Startup.Auth which I had by default in VS15. I've downloaded Entity framework through Nuget but still can't see them in my model and app_Start folders.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean they are missing? The IDE does not create classes for you. Are you trying to start a new project using a built in template?

Comment: @Igor When I create a new MVC project in VS15 I have the files mentioned by default. When I create a new MVC project in VS17 does file isn't there by default.

Comment: What edition of VS15?

Comment: @Igor Community edition

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, and found the solution [here](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/57692311-82e8-4296-bb34-cbc18c454720?category=visualstudiogeneral)

> if you want add IdentityModel and Startup.Auth you just need to change the option to "Individual User Accounts" after click change the authentication button and select Individual User Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change Authentication from No Authentication to individual User Account or something else when you create a project, by default is No Authentication that's why you don't get the IdentityModels.cs class